# How to pass event object from paper-button click to angular.dart's function?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, paper-elements

I have am using `paper-button` for click event and trying to add `on-click="angularComponent.function"` where `angularComponent.function` is a function in a angular.dart's component within which this paper button is being used, but the click is not triggering the function call. However, with `on-click="angularComponent.function('a','b','c')"`, it does trigger function on click (courtesy of `angular_node_bind` module). This means that I can't get hold of event object, which is otherwise passed to pure dart/polymer element function. How to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Angular you usually pass `$event` to have the event object available in the handler

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'my-cmp',
    publishAs: 'cmp',
    template: r'<div><paper-button ng-click="cmp.clickHandler($event)" label="click me"></paper-button></div>'
)
class MyComponent {
  void clickHandler(dom.Event event) {
    print('clicked: $event');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that, it doesn't work. Also, I suppose $event comes only for ng-* bindings, which doesn't work on `paper-button` either.

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot the `ng` at the beginning instead of `on`. I tried it and it works

Comment: woah! I had done exactly similar thing, but hadn't worked earlier! may be it was multiple changes from different places :-/, anyways, thanks for this!